# shell script grep to grep a string

Tags: bash, grep

The output is blank fr the below script. What is it missing? I am trying to grep a string

```
#!/bin/ksh    
file=$abc_def_APP_13.4.5.2    
if grep -q abc_def_APP $file; then
 echo "File Found"
else
 echo "File not Found"
fi
```

Comment: Why does the #! line say ksh?

Comment: What is the value of `file` supposed to be? I suspect you might have an issue on the RHS of that assignment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `bash`, use the `<<<` redirection from a string (a ['Here string'](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings)):

```
if grep -q abc_def_APP <<< $file
```

In other shells, you may need to use:

```
if echo $file | grep -q abc_def_APP
```

I put my `then` on the next line; if you want your `then` on the same line, then add `; then` after what I wrote.

---

Note that this assignment:

```
file=$abc_def_APP_13.4.5.2
```

is pretty odd; it takes the value of an environment variable `${abc_def_APP_13}` and adds `.4.5.2` to the end (it must be an env var since we can see the start of the script).  You probably intended to write:

```
file=abc_def_APP_13.4.5.2
```

In general, you should enclose references to variables holding file names in double quotes to avoid problems with spaces etc in the file names.  It is not critical here, but good practices are good practices:

```
if grep -q abc_def_APP <<< "$file"
if echo "$file" | grep -q abc_def_APP
```

Comment: If I use `if echo $file | grep -q abc_def_APP` it is printing the content of $file, which I dont want to

Comment: You chose the `-q` option to make `grep` run in 'quiet' mode (per [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)); it should not output anything.  If your version of `grep` has a different understanding of `-q`, you'll have to look at your man `grep`'s man page, or redirect to `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 3):

Yuck! Use the shell's string matching

```
if [[ "$file" == *abc_def_APP* ]]; then ...
```

Comment: don't you risk matching multiple files with `*abc_def_APP*` and ruin the condition in the process? What if `$file` is `abc_def_APP1` and `*abc_def_APP*` expanded to `abc_def_APP1 abc_def_APP2`, the condition would evaluate as false.

Comment: and about the "Yuck!" part ; I totally agree with you! the whole of the unix (unix-like) command shell is f'ing disgusting... but you can't live without it, can you?

Comment: Inside double brackets, we're pattern matching against the left-hand string, not matching filenames.